# SQL Insert Code Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am trying to execute the following SQL code on SQL Server, but 0 rows are affected.

```
INSERT INTO IV10201 (ITEMNMBR, TRXLOCTN, QTYTYPE, DOCDATE, RCTSEQNM, ORIGINDOCTYPE, ORIGINDOCID, LNSEQNBR, CMPNTSEQ, QTYSOLD, UNITCOST, IVIVINDX, IVIVOFIX, SRCRCTSEQNM, TRXREFERENCE, PCHSRCTY)
    SELECT 
        ITEMNMBR, TRXLOCTN, QTYTYPE, DOCDATE, 218, 
        ORIGINDOCTYPE, ORIGINDOCID, LNSEQNBR, CMPNTSEQ, 15.500000,
        UNITCOST, IVIVINDX, IVIVOFIX, 0, TRXREFERENCE, PCHSRCTY
    FROM 
        IV10201 
    WHERE 
        itemNmbr = 'N-LB-00039-0015-0004' 
        AND trxLoctn = 'KATAMYA' 
        AND qtyType = 1 
        AND docDate = '2016-02-08 00:00:00' 
        AND rctseqnm = 157 
        AND srcrctseqnm = 64
```

I am not getting any error messages, just that 0 rows were affected. Any idea what is the problem with my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like the `SELECT` found no records.  If there's nothing matching that `WHERE` clause, then there's nothing to insert.

Comment: I would be inclined to check the docdate, is it always time 00:00:00 ? any other time would make the condition false

Comment: Does select query return any data when run directly against the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your select query does not return anything, that's your problem most likely. Try running your query without insert and see what results you get.

Comment: I cannot believe I didn’t think of that!! I feel very stupid! Thanks mate (Y)

Comment: @Y2H Happens, everyone has these moments! : )